# java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: mes no válido on select query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a query working on DataGrip but not working on Spring boot app.
FORMAT of date on db is: 19-JUN-01 12.00.00.000000 AM

I have tried to change format of date but it does not help.

```
SELECT 
to_char(to_date(substr(NVL(w.BIRTHDATE, SYSDATE), 1, 9), 'DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') dob
FROM DBNAME.USERS
```

Exception I get

```
 ORA-01843: mes no válido; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: mes no válido

        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:84)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1442)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:693)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:747)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:215)
        at com.voida.panamax.service.impl.ApiServiceImpl.lambda$init$3(ApiServiceImpl.java:240)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: mes no válido

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:677)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of methods available in oracle to transform date in any readable format.

As you have a date stored in a string, you will need to convert it to date and use the appropriate method to show it in the desired format.

In your case, you can use the following:

-- Updated my answer as `BIRTHDATE` is a string.

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(NVL(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(w.BIRTHDATE, 1, 18), 'RR-MON-DD HH24.MI.SS'), SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') DOB
FROM DBNAME.USERS;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=42eb4407ee2e3eb203efc3877ab2038b)

Cheers!!

-- UPDATE --

-- If the format of your stored date is 'dd-mon-yy' then use the following:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(NVL(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(w.BIRTHDATE, 1, 18), 'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS'), SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') DOB
FROM DBNAME.USERS;
```

See updated [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3500f1497aec7e84782c56f918df7652), How format changes the entire output. In the second query, I have used 'DD-MON-RR'

Cheers!!

Comment: Format of BIRTHDAT COLUMN is 19-JUN-01 12.00.00.000000 and it is a string column , not date

Comment: I received error on your query 

[42000][1722] ORA-01722: invalid number
[2019-08-16 14:25:33] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error : 1722, Position : 16, Sql = SELECT
[2019-08-16 14:25:33] to_char(NVL(w.BIRTHDATE, SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') dob
[2019-08-16 14:25:33] FROM DB.USERS w, OriginalSql = SELECT
[2019-08-16 14:25:33] to_char(NVL(w.BIRTHDATE, SYSDATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') dob
[2019-08-16 14:25:33] FROM DB.USERS w, Error Msg = ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: i started receiving new error: [22008][1847] ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Comment: one of the main problems is my query works on DataGrip but not in APP.

Comment: What is the format of your date that is stored in the string?: 'dd-mon-yy' or 'yy-mon-dd'?

Comment: DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM

Comment: Now query works on DataGrip but not from APP. All other queries works OK.

Comment: error is same. ORA-01843: mes no válido on select query